# random numbers in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following table created using java as the front end and mysql as the backend.

```
mysql> select * from consumer9;
-------------             
4 rows in set (0.13 sec)



Service_ID          Service_Type                            consumer_feedback 

100                    computing                                          -1
35                     printer                                             0
73                    computing                                           -1
50                     data                                                1
```

I have generated these values using the concept of random numbers.
I want to get the output where the Service_types(Printer,Computing,data) are distributed uniformally in all the tables with the feedback values of 1 occuring most number of times.

Comment: I'm still not understanding what exactly the question is here. Are you asking how to generate data that fits a particular distribution pattern?

Comment: Your database schema is wrong.  Each consumer shouldn't have it's own table.  A separate `consumers` table or something with foreign keys from `services` or something.  Also: `SELECT service_type, COUNT(*) FROM services WHERE (consumer_feedback == 1) GROUP BY service_type`

Comment: question is not very clear - could you please explain the last line?

Answer (score 5):

The class [`java.util.Random`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) can generate pseudo-random numbers having a reasonably uniform distribution. Given a `List` of your service type:

```
List<String> services = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("COMPUTER", "DATA", "PRINTER"));
```

it is easy to select one at random:

```
String s = services.get(rnd.nextInt(services.size()));
```

Similarly, one of a list of feedback values may be chosen:

```
List<String> feedbacks = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("1", "0", "-1"));
String s = feedbacks.get(rnd.nextInt(feedbacks.size()));
```

One simple expedient to get a different distribution is to "stack the deck". For example,

```
Arrays.asList("1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "-1"));
```

would produce 1, 0, and -1 with probability <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>, <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub>, and <sup>1</sup>/<sub>6</sub>, respectively. You can arrange more elaborate partitions using [`nextGaussian()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()) and a suitable [confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_confidence_intervals).

This approach should only be used for generating test data.

Addendum: [*The Apache Commons Math Guide*](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/index.html) includes a chapter on [*Data Generation*](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/random.html), with informative links and documentation concerning other probability distributions.