# How to randomize enum elements?

Tags: java, random, enums

Say you have an `enum` with some elements

```
public enum LightColor {
   RED, YELLOW, GREEN
}
```

And would like to randomly pick any color from it.

I put colors into a

```
public List<LightColor> lightColorChoices = new ArrayList<LightColor>();

lightColorChoices.add(LightColor.GREEN);
lightColorChoices.add(LightColor.YELLOW);
lightColorChoices.add(LightColor.RED);
```

And then picked a random color like:

```
this.lightColor = lightColorChoices.get((int) (Math.random() * 3));
```

All of this (while working fine) seems needlessly complicated. Is there a simplier way to pick a random enum element?

Comment: as your fellow developer for a random number ? ... sorry, no.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269250/random-value-from-enum-with-probability

Comment: I think this one is more akin to the problem at hand (hint: look for trashgod's answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972392/java-pick-a-random-value-from-an-enum

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Java's enums are actually fully capable Objects.  You can add a method to the `enum` declaration

```
public enum LightColor {
    Green,
    Yellow,
    Red;

    public static LightColor getRandom() {
        return values()[(int) (Math.random() * values().length)];
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to use it like this:

```
LightColor randomLightColor = LightColor.getRandom();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
LightColor random = LightColor.values()[(int)(Math.random()*(LightColor.values().length))];
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [Enum.values()](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/Enumvalues.htm) to get all available options and use the [Random.nextInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) method specifying the max value. eg:

```
private static Random numberGenerator = new Random();
public <T> T randomElement(T[] elements)
  return elements[numberGenerator.nextInt(elements.length)];
}
```

This can then be called as such:

```
LightColor randomColor = randomElement(LightColor.values());
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting Random.nextInt() instead of multiplying by size

Answer (score 3):

This should be just easy as shown below

```
LightColor[] values = LightColor.values();
LightColor value = values[(int) (Math.random() * 3)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could associate an integer id to each enum color, and have a valueOf(int id) method that returns the corresponding color. This will help you get rid of the list..

Tiberiu

Answer (score 0):

So reading Kowser's answer, I came up with something here.
Given an enum ChatColor containing different colors, you could do the following:

```
private ChatColor getRandomColor() {
    ChatColor randomColor = ChatColor.values()[random.nextInt(ChatColor
            .values().length - 1)];
    ChatColor[] blacklist = { ChatColor.BOLD, ChatColor.ITALIC,
            ChatColor.MAGIC, ChatColor.RESET, ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH,
            ChatColor.UNDERLINE };
    while (Arrays.asList(blacklist).contains(randomColor)) {
        randomColor = ChatColor.values()[random
                .nextInt(ChatColor.values().length)];
    }
    return randomColor;
}
```

and even have a blacklist.