# Static (and final) field initialization in an enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, static, initialization, final

Say I have this enumerated type of Colours as follows:

```
public enum Colour
{
    RED, GREEN, BLUE;
}
```

I want to randomize a colour out of those three, following the suggestion found over there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114214/2736228

But I don't want to make a call to `values()` over and over again, so, I came up with something as follows:

```
public enum Colour
{
    RED, GREEN, BLUE;

    private static final Colour[] Values = values();

    public static Colour random()
    {
        return Values[(int) (Math.random() * Values.length)];
    }
}
```

Question is, will it work, always?

What confuses me here, is that when the initialization of this `private static final` field occurs. It should be happening after the full list of enumeration is completed. I don't see it happening anytime soon, but still, I want to make sure.

Comment: By the way it is proper convention in Java to name final constants with all caps.

Comment: but it feels like you waste the final variable, have you measured strong performance improvement comparing to `values()[...]` ?

Comment: @xerx593 No, I haven't measured anything at all. It just didn't feel right that I will be going to create something just momentarily to destroy, though I think it happens anywhere else in my code almost all the time.

Comment: And this doesn't even do what you want: The array is mutable. Be clear and follow convention (use the method) until you have a demonstrated performance problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this initialization will always work.  The enum constants are always listed first, and the [JLS, Section 8.9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3), guarantees that they will be initialized before any other normal `static` variables.

> For each enum constant c declared in the body of the declaration of E, E has an implicitly declared public static final field of type E that has the same name as c. The field has a variable initializer consisting of c, and is annotated by the same annotations as c.
>
> These fields are implicitly declared in the same order as the corresponding enum constants, before any static fields explicitly declared in the body of the declaration of E.

All `static` fields are initialized in order as if they were a single text block, so all of your enum constants will be initialized before `Values` is initialized by calling `values()`.

Incidentally, `static final` variables are usually named with all capitalized letters, e.g. `VALUES`, per standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: Yes for all, except for the last sentence: [constants, not `static final` variables, should be capitalized](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). You want to be pedantic? So am I. A `static final` variable is not always a constant. Example: a `List` that can be updated dynamically can be `static final` but is certainly not a constant. I agree this is not the case here, but it's worth being complete since you felt the need to mention it.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Well it is a naming standard, and one I like to stick to. Java doesn't really support constant lists syntactically (compile-time), so you would have to use a Immutable list implementation. Immutable lists fail against change only during run-time ... unfortunately ...

Comment: @JoD. Well, please check [this page](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2.4-constant-names) which clearly shows the difference between constants and other fields. So the two most popular naming conventions (Sun/Oracle in my previous comment and Google in this one) clearly state that there is a difference between constants and `static final` fields, and both state that only constants should be capitalized. So I fail to see which "naming standard" you're referring to. Would you enlighten me?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Google, yes, but not so sure about oracle. Oracle/sun's document refers to something named an ANSI constant. That seems to be documentation inherited from C/c++, and otherwise no reference to the immutability of an object. Either way, if that is what you follow, good for you. Me on the other hand, I find it sometimes hard to implement, or sometimes too much overhead to make things completely immutable, so I just declare my intention to use it as a constant.

Comment: @JoD. [Whatever](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/constant#Noun) [you](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constant) [say](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/constant).