# Execute CommandA A% of time, CommandB B% of time, CommandC C% of time ----- CommandZ Z% of time by using Random Number

Tags: java, random

**Problem Statement**: Execute Various Command randomly by matching its percentage.
like execute CommandA 50% of time and commandB 25% of the time and commandC 15% of time and etc etc and total percentage should be 100%.

**My Question is- Execute CommandA A% of time, CommandB B% 
           of time, CommandC C% of time ----- CommandZ Z% of time. 
           And total percentage should be 100% and at the end I can see
           how much times each command is being executed and what is 
           the percentage of each command(means how many times each command is 
           being executed in terms of percentage) after total execution is complete.**

**Idea:-**
Generate a random number between 1 and 100 and see if any of the percentage fall in the category

```
List<Double> comamndDistribution = new ArrayList<Double>();

    /* Commands to execute. Here I have Z command 
    *  and total percentage should be 100% (A+B+C+D+...+Z=100%)
    */
        comamndDistribution.add(A%); // command A
        comamndDistribution.add(B%); // command B
        comamndDistribution.add(C%); // command C
        comamndDistribution.add(D%); // command D
        comamndDistribution.add(E%); // command E
        -----------
        -----------
        comamndDistribution.add(Z%); // command Z

private Command getNextCommandToExecute() {

    for (int i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
       // generating a random number between 1 and 100
      int random = r.nextInt(100-1) + 1;

    /* My Question is- Execute CommandA A% of time, CommandB B% 
       of time, CommandC C% of time ----- Command Z Z% of time. 
       And total percentage should be 100% and at the end I can see
       how much times each command is being executed and what is 
       the percentage of each command(means how many times each command is 
       being executed in terms of percentage) after total execution is complete.
    */
        }
}

/* Get the next command to execute by maintaining the Percentage of 
    each command randomly*/
    Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
```

***Let me make it more clear- My Question is- Execute CommandA A% of time, CommandB B% of time, CommandC C% of time ----- Command N N% of time by using Random Number. And total percentage should be 100%.***

P.S: I think this question has been asked few times, but it is not the way I wanted it. So I thought to put it again as a question by posting my code what I did so far.

**Update:- I have updated the question by removing the previous code that I wrote with another logic so that people can understand it more.**

Comment: You may wish to post your question text in the body of your post, not as a comment in the code where extends out of the window and is hard to read.

Comment: This is not an homework, I am working on a project. If this was an homework I would have tag as an homework.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know what your question is. Do you have a bug or exception? Are you trying to find which command is hit by a random number `p` in `[0, 99]`?

Comment: @David, Let me make it more clear- My Question is- Execute CommandA A% of time, CommandB B% of time, CommandC C% of time ----- Command N N% of time. And total percentage should be 100%. And have some kind of percentage ratio at the end, how much got executed after the total execution is done.

Comment: Yu  might look at the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2343296/230513).

Comment: I honestly feel like this could be done better with a shell script...

Comment: But it has to be done in Java only that's the problem.

Comment: *"it has to be done in Java"*  Why?

Comment: Actually I said that way because I am currently on my project in Java and I don't know Shell Script that much.

Comment: You should do that thing in shell script and execute at runtime. You can post your question about shell script designing. Take advantage of Linux system.

Comment: I understand your point. But I don't think so I can do that as it's a project and I need to do that in Java :(. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: So this is essentially a puzzle: find 26 numbers that add to 100.  Then let A = 100, B = C = D = ... = Y = 0.  Always execute CommandA.  Done.  :-P

Comment: I don't know who has voted to close the question. I think Question is clear enough. If something is not clear I will try to answer your query.

Comment: Selecting a command to run is easy enough: Assign each command a bin, say A should have a probability of 20, so it gets [0,20), B should have 10% so you give it [20-30) etc. Assuming your randomn numbers are equally distributed, simply find the command that has the right bin and execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it a similar way to Adam Liss, but it's turned out more verbose.

Again, I thought you can't rely on the provided commands always adding up to 100%, so I've coped with that, but my way requires a method call to renormalise proportions (so a little more error prone).

```
import java.util.*;

/** 
  A basic 'Command' class for testing
*/
class Command {
  private String id;
  public Command (String pId) {
    this.id = pId;
  }
  public void execute () {
    System.out.println ("Command: "+id);
  }
}

/** The class that does the random selection bit of magic */
public class CommandDist {

  /** an internal helper class to manage proportions and the command */
  class Cmd {
    Command command;                 // the command that will get executed
    double assignedProportion;       // weight assigned when added
    double cumulativeProportion;     // recalculated later to between 0 and 1

    public Cmd (Command c, double proportion) {
      this.command = c;
      this.assignedProportion = proportion;
      this.cumulativeProportion = 0.0;
    }
  }

  // the list I'm using 
  private List<Cmd> commandDistribution = new ArrayList<Cmd>();
  private java.util.Random myRandom = new java.util.Random();

  void addCommand (Command command, double proportion) {
    commandDistribution.add ( new Cmd (command, proportion));
  }

  // ** MUST BE CALLED **, after adding all the commands, to normalise the proportions.
  // you could do this tidier by setting a flag in add, and checking it in
  // getNextCommandToExecute
  void normaliseProportion() {
    double total = 0;
    double cumulativeProp = 0;
    for (Cmd cmd: commandDistribution) {
       total += cmd.assignedProportion;
    }
    for (Cmd cmd: commandDistribution) {
       cumulativeProp += cmd.assignedProportion/total;
       cmd.cumulativeProportion = cumulativeProp;
    }
  }


  private Command getNextCommandToExecute () {
    double d = myRandom.nextDouble();
    for (Cmd cmd: commandDistribution) {
      if (d < cmd.cumulativeProportion) {
        return cmd.command;
      }
    }
    // theoretically, should not get here.  Never rely on theoretically.
    return commandDistribution.get(0).command;

  }

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    CommandDist cd = new CommandDist();
    Command c; 

    cd.addCommand (new Command ("A"), 50.0);
    cd.addCommand (new Command ("B"), 20.0);
    cd.addCommand (new Command ("C"), 15.0);
    cd.addCommand (new Command ("D"), 10.0);

    cd.normaliseProportion();


    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
       c = cd.getNextCommandToExecute();
       c.execute();
    }

  }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Command: C
Command: A
Command: C
Command: A
Command: D
```

And generally distributes like this (different counts each run, of course).

```
java CommandDist | sort | uniq -c
   5183 Command: A
   2151 Command: B
   1595 Command: C
   1071 Command: D
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you asked, but I think it's what you meant.

```
class RandomCommands {
  // A Map that associates each command with a threshold from 0 - totalWeights.
  // The order of iteration is the same as the order of insertion.
  private Map<int, Command> commands = new LinkedHashMap<int, Command>>();

  // Running total of the weights of all of the commands.  The likelihood that
  // particular command will be executed is its weight / totalWeights.
  private int totalWeights = 0;

  // Adds a command with the specified weight, which can be any positive integer.
  public void addCommand(int weight, Command command) {
    commands.put(totalWeights, command);
    totalWeights += weight;
  }

  // Chooses a random command.
  public Command getRandomCommand() {
    // Choose a random number to select a command.
    int selector = Random.nextInt(totalWeights);

    // Find the corresponding command.
    for (Element<int, Command> command : commands) {
      if (command.key >= selector) {
        return command.value;
      }
      selector -= command.key;
    }
  }
}
```

**Example:**

Suppose we have 3 commands with weights 20, 20, and 40.  Since the total of the weights is 80, we can calculate:

- Each of the first 2 commands will be chosen 20/80 = 1/4 = 25% of the time.
- The 3<sup>rd</sup> command will be chosen 40/80 = 1/2 = 50% of the time.

The `commands` Map will contain the entries:

```
<0,  Command1>
<20, Command2>
<40, Command3>
```

Each time `getRandomCommand()` is called, it will choose a random number from 0 to 79.  It will return one of the commands as follows:

```
selector   command   frequency of execution
————————   ———————   ———————————————————————————————————————
 0 - 19    Command1  (1 + 19 -  0) / 80 = 20/80 = 1/4 = 25%
20 - 39    Command2  (1 + 39 - 20) / 80 = 20/80 = 1/4 = 25%
40 - 79    Command3  (1 + 79 - 40) / 80 = 40/80 = 1/2 = 50%
```