# Limiting duplicate random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I just want to know how to limit to number of times a random number appears. I have generated random numbers of 1 to 10 and want to limit each number to appear 4 times.

```
myArray[i][j] = rand.nextInt(11);

for (int i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
       myArray[i][j] = rand.nextInt(11);
       System.out.print(" " + myArray[i][j]);
```

The code above creates the randoms numbers. Just want to limit them.

Comment: What are myArray[][] dimensions?)

Comment: How many times do you call rand.nextInt(11) i.e. how many elements you have in your array?

Comment: Several approaches are examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2339508/230513).

Comment: At least not more often than 40 times :-) I hope...

Comment: I'd suggest creating a loop with another array of counters and making another loop with an if sentence in it that if a certain counter gets over 4 you randomize another number.

Comment: Oh by the way... you're including the zero in the results. You probably should use (Random.nextInt(10) + 1), instead

Comment: I edited the code above. I have a 2D array that stores a 15 x 20 table. The code will randomly fill in each row and column with random numbers between 1 and 10. I want it to limit duplicate randoms in each row to 4. Is that possible?

Comment: Fill an array of length 40 with the numbers 1-10 repeated 4 times.  Then for each row, do a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_Shuffle) of the array and select the desired number of elements. You'll only need the one array, because you can shuffle it as many times as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution stores the result in arrayList:

```
public class Example {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int range = 10;
    int[] numbers = new int[range + 1];
    int sum = 0;
    final int noOfOccurances = 4;
    final int size = range * noOfOccurances;
    Arrays.fill(numbers, 0);
    Random generator = new Random();
    List<Integer> numbersArray = new ArrayList<>();
    while (sum != size) {
        int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(range) + 1;
        if (numbers[randomNumber] != noOfOccurances) {
            numbers[randomNumber]++;
            sum++;
            numbersArray.add(randomNumber);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(numbersArray);
}
}
```

Comment: nice, I copied your idea in my response

Comment: @ring0 there is just one loop so can you please explain why complexity is O(n²)?

Comment: I was wrong: complexity is O(size) - because your program doesn't work :-) `numbers[randomNumber]` is never incremented so the prog stops after *size* loops, but you may get 2 `1`, 5 `2`,.. Once your algo is fixed (increment where *sum* is), you see that when `sum == size-1` the last number has a `9/10` probability to get randomly selected, i.e. on average 10 loops to get that number. The proba decreases with previous numbers - but if you are unlucky 4 last same number are to be found! or on average 40 loops... Didn't do the calculation, but should be close to O(n²)

Comment: If the range and number of occurances is fixed, and you generate the whole list of numbers, this approach deliveres the same result as putting all numbers in a list and then shuffle the list, but is extremely inefficient. See the answer of giorashc (comments included) for a much better solution with the same outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are limited to 10 * 4 = 40 numbers you can use a list and randomize the index :

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) 
      numbers.add(i);
}
```

And then when you assign a random number :

```
int i = rand.nextInt(numbers.size());
myArray[i][j] = numbers.get(i);
numbers.remove(i);
```

This assumes your two dimensional will not contain more then 40 numbers

Comment: You won't need the indirection via a random index, if you just [shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) the list and then always remove the first or last entry.

Comment: You would only shuffle the list after creation, not on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the count of the generated int's in an array, or Map, or anything?

```
Map<Integer, Integer> randomCounts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
... your for loops
myArray[i][j] = rand.nextInt(11);
if (randomCounts.containsKey(myArray[i][j])) { 
   randomCounts.put(myArray[i][j],randomCounts.get(myArray[i][j])+1);
} else {
   randomCounts.put(myArray[i][j],1);
}
```

And if you want to check them, just iterate through your map, and voilá. :)

Comment: As long as the number of generated values is fixed, I would just use an Array of ints and do `randomCounts[randomNumber]++`
But this alone does not limit the repetition of a single number, it only logs it...

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for the review! I choose Map over arrays, because this way it is easier to check if any of the numbers is generated more than 5 times - randomCounts.containsValue(5) will work instead of me (but Collections will do that for arrays as well). :) Why do you use arrays btw?

Comment: Just because arrays have less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method to check if the generated number exists more than 4 times in the array and create a new random number if it does. It should look like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class rndNumberGenerator {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int[][] myArray = new int[2][5];
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNumber;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                do {
                    randomNumber = rand.nextInt(11);
                } while(overMax(myArray, randomNumber) == true);

                myArray[i][j] = randomNumber;

                System.out.print(" " + myArray[i][j]);

            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean overMax(int[][] array, int number) {

        int max = 4;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                if (array[i][j] == number) {
                    count++;
                }

            }
        }

        if (count >= max)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

Hope this helped you, if you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I take suggestion by **pshemek** (vote up): instead the `ArrayList`, I use the `Set` because it can't contain duplicate numbers and you have'nt to espicitate control.

An implementation: the *copy{right, left}* is of **pshemek**, I had only extended the idea:)

```
public class Example {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[11];
        int sum = 0;
        final int range = 10;
        final int noOfOccurances = 4;
        Arrays.fill(numbers, 0);
        Random generator = new Random();
        Set<Integer> numbersArray = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        while (sum != range * noOfOccurances) {
            int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(range) + 1;
            sum++;//correction for first comment
            numbersArray.add(randomNumber); // randomNumber will never be twice: a Set cointains ever one and only one instance of an determinated element
        }
        System.out.println(numbersArray);
    }

  }//end class
```

Comment: where do you increment sum.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own:

```
public static class CountedRandom {
    // My rng.
    Random rand = new Random();
    // Keeps track of the counts so far.
    Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    // The limit I must apply.
    final int limit;

    public CountedRandom(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public int nextInt(int l) {
        int r;
        do {
            // Keep getting a new number until we hit one that has'n been overused.
            r = rand.nextInt(l);
        } while (count(r) >= limit);
        return r;
    }

    private int count(int r) {
        // How many times have we seen this one so far.
        Integer counted = counts.get(r);
        if ( counted == null ) {
            // Never!
            counted = new Integer(0);
        }
        // Remember the new value.
        counts.put(r, counted + 1);
        // Returns 0 first time around.
        return counted;
    }
}

public void test() {
    CountedRandom cr = new CountedRandom(4);
    for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
        System.out.print(cr.nextInt(4)+",");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Note that this **will hang** if you ask for too may numbers in too small a range (as I have in my test).

Prints

```
2,0,1,2,1,1,3,3,0,3,0,2,2,0,1,3,
```

and then hangs.